# GATE with Python

Tags: python, nlp, java

I am working on named entity recognition project and find **[GATE](https://gate.ac.uk/)** very useful. But I couldn't find a Python connector for GATE yet. Is it possible or is there a way to integrate GATE work flows into Python ? Or how can I write **JAPE** rules for extracting entities in python ?

Comment: Are you talking about [that GATE](https://gate.ac.uk/family/process.html)? The answer depends on what level of integration you mean. For a basic direction, I suggest you to search for Java-Python interoperability software modules.